# How to make 'create' method be useable from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

this is my method

```
def add
    @result
    @log = Log.new(params[:log])
    if @log.save
      result = "success";
    else
      result = "fail";
    end
    render :json => result
end
```

and this is my routes.rb

```
match "/logs/add/:value/:category/:note/:own" => "logs#add"
```

when i try putting this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/logs/add/338/testcat/testnote/testown
```

and it returns the json correctly and new item was added to the database but
all of the fields(value,category,note,own) are null.

please help :(

---

I've already solved the above problem, but

What if i want to create multiple objects by sending from 1 url to my ruby. 
Ex:

> localhost:3000/logs/add/338/testcat/testnote/testown

The above request will create only 1 log to my database
If I want to create many logs by using the above solution, I have to send one url for one log.
I want my ruby to be able to create multiple logs from 1 url.
I mean that I can create many logs by sending only one url to the server.
What `routing,method,url` should be? 
(I heard something about "`url/add/param1&&param2`" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `Log.new(params[:log])` but there isn't a `log` parameter in the request.

You can fix this by updating your `#new` call:

```
@log = Log.new({
    :value => params[:value],
    :category => params[:category],
    :note => params[:note],
    :own => params[:own]
})
```

but bear in mind that you will then have a GET request which changes your database state. This is potentially a security flaw, because a potential attacker could get you to update your database just by following a link (from their website, in an email etc). This could even be a problem *without* a malicious attacker - Google will happily follow GET links - and even if you hide your site behind a login, it's not impossible to think of a situation where Chrome may try and speed up your browsing session by "intelligently" preloading a link it spots in the page before you click it.

Generally all of your data-changing actions should be limited to POST requests

Comment: I'd give you an extra upvote for the "GET requests should *get* data, not create it" part but alas I only have one account.

Comment: thanks, this is work. but this website is just my little project at the college. I won't deploy this web, just use it locally to do a presentation. anyway, thx

Comment: Hmm, I have one more question. What if i want to create multiple objects by sending from 1 url to my ruby. Ex: "http://localhost:3000/logs/add/338/testcat/testnote/testown" << this will create only 1 log to my database, what if I want my ruby to be able to create multiple logs from 1 url, what routing,method,url should be? (I heard something about "url/add/param1&&param2" ?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify parameters like `:note` in your route its value will be passed in `params` hash, but it won't be automatically passed to your model.

`params` hash will have keys `:value, :category, :note, :own` but not `:log`. To initialize properly your model you can do smth like that:

```
Log.new :value    => params[:value],
        :category => params[:category],
        :note     => params[:note],  
        :own      => params[:own]
```

or just

```
Log.new params
```

but in last case you should ensure that there are no other parameters in `params` hash but attributes for your model.